# Updating UI as the result of a request handler

Tags: ios, swift, gcdwebserver

I have a setup like this;

```
startup() {
    ...
    self.gcdWebServer.addHandlerForMethod("GET", path: "/hide", 
        requestClass: GCDWebServerRequest.self, asyncProcessBlock: {request in self.hide()})
    ...
}

func hide() -> GCDWebServerDataResponse {
    self.view.hidden = true;
    print("hide")
    return GCDWebServerDataResponse(statusCode: 200)
}
```

When a request to `/hide` is made, the console shows the `print()` call immediately, but the view does not disappear for some arbitrary delay, somewhere between 10-30 seconds.

How can I have the request immediately result in the view being hidden?

Comment: Try calling `self.view.hidden = true` from the main thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, calling hidden on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   self.view.hidden = true;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap you r UI related login inside dispatch async and run it on main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

    self.view.hidden = true;

 })
```

Answer (score 3):

**Rewrite your `hide` method as below.
You need update UI on main thread only.**

```
func hide() -> GCDWebServerDataResponse {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.view.hidden = true
    })
    print("hide")
    return GCDWebServerDataResponse(statusCode: 200)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UI update code  write in main thread only.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        self.view.hidden = true;

     })
```